# Extending ring metric to arbitrary module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I am working on my own on an idea I had and this one is a bit difficult so I am seeking a bit of inspiration and to see what already exists. Let $R$ be a given ring with a metric $d$ and $M$ being an $R$-module. If $M$ is free finitely generated one could define, or extend, our $d$ to $d^\ast:M\to\mathbb{R}$ by having
$$d^\ast(x,y)=\sqrt[m]{\sum_i^n d(x_i,y_i)^m}$$
with $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n)$ and $x_i\in R$. I have not worked through it all quite here but I am fairly certain it works out as a normal metric as it's basically just the euclidean one, or the product metric. My question is however is there a way to define $d^\ast$ for a general module $M$ that is not necessarily free? Or is it such that different module types require different definitions? Or is it simply not possible to give all modules a metric if the ring has a metric?

**Addition**: The metric in question is a metric that can be used for the completion of $R$ so the metric is a non-trivial one, what I am also after is that $d^\ast$ is to be defined relative to $d$ through some mean. I had an idea for a one dimensional finitely generated module (which I feel can be extended), namely
$$d^\ast(a,b)=\inf_{r,q\in R}\{d(r,q):\exists n,m\in M: rn=a, qm=b\}$$

Comment: Do you ask for your metric $d$ to be induced by a norm on $R$? If not, what properties do you want $d$ to satisfy with respect to the ring structure of $R$?

Comment: I am saying that $d$ is a metric on $R$ and I am trying to see if there is a way to extend this metric to work on a general case for $R$-modules. The metric $d$ is given and known prior.

Comment: What I meant is, is $d$ just a metric, or does it somehow respect the ring structure of $R$, for instance by having $d(0,x+y)\leq d(0,x)+d(0,y)$, or any other axiom involving the operations of $R$?

Comment: It's just an ordinary metric, if it fullfills those or not is given but if one has ideas involving a metric that is respectful like that I'd be interested in seeing it. HOwever in this question that is not given and cannot be assumed.

Comment: The reason I ask is that without any required properties, you could always define the discrete metric on $M$, just as you could on any set.  I'm guessing this is not what you want.

Comment: No, this is related to the completion of a ring so th'd be of little interest or value.

Comment: The link to completion of a ring is not obvious from your question.  Perhaps it would be a good idea to include it?

Comment: You make a valid point, I will